# Returning variables from complex function to use in another

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++

I'm confused, how can I use `GetCursorPos` from `GetPoint()` to get POINT in ClickSimulationMove and then use that exact point in `MouseReturn` in `ClickSimulationClick`. Sadly I can't stick this Click and Move functions together.

The Code:

```
FB::variant TestPluginAPI::ClickSimulationClick()
{
POINT pt = GetPoint();
ShowCursor(true);
MouseLeft();
MouseReturn(pt.x, pt.y);
ShowCursor(true);
return 0;
}

POINT TestPluginAPI::GetPoint()
{
POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);
return pt;
}

FB::variant TestPluginAPI::ClickSimulationMove()
{
MouseMove(-325, 605);
return 0;
}
```

ClickSimulationMove() goes first, then ClickSimulationClick(), therefore GetPoint() gets POINT of already moved mouse, but i need the POINT of not yet moved mouse to return to that place.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now exactly?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a note of the mouse position **before** you move it. So call GetCursorPos before MouseMove. Remember this position in a variable that you pass to the function that restores the cursor position.

Comment: But how can I then use this POINT from `Move` in `Click` ?
I was trying to return point in `POINT TestPluginAPI::ClickSimulationMove()` but it gives some weird errors

Comment: I can make `TestPluginAPI::ClickSimulationMove(POINT pt) {..... POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);}` but am how can i pass it then in `Click` if it's two different functions.

Comment: Pass the point as a parameter to any function that needs it.

Comment: Oh, that's obvious, i will try.